# Retrive value from plist file based on date

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have been searching how to do this for a while now with no luck..
How can i retrieve the value stored in a plist file according to today's date which is checked against the Key in the plist file.

[image]

For example as the date today is 2013-05-10 the code should output 5 to the console (the corresponding key in the plist file.
Or for eg. the date today is 2013-05-13 the code should output 6 to the console(the corresponding key in the plist file.

Here's my code to load the plist file into a dictionary:

```
NSString *something = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Calender" ofType:@"plist"];
_calender = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:something];
NSDate *eventDate = [_calender objectForKey:@"date"];
```

Comment: This is quite trivial, doable without doing anything but firing up the docs of `NSDictionary` and `NSDate`.

Comment: i am just accessing the file at the moment and created it into a dictionary but am not sure how to compare current date with the Key in the plist file

Comment: Show the code you are actually using.

Comment: NSString *something = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Calender" ofType:@"plist"];
    _calender = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:something];
    NSDate *eventDate = [_calender objectForKey:@"date"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary has date strings for keys and the corresponding values are strings.

Your code to load the dictionary is fine. The part you are missing is generating the proper key from the current date.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// Use this special locale when generating fixed format date strings
NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[df setLocale:posix];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Now you can use `dateString` as the key to your dictionary to lookup the value:

```
NSString *dateValue = _calender[dateString]; // using your misspelling of calendar
```

`dateValue` will be `@"5"`, `@"6"`, or nil. It will be `nil` if today's date isn't in the dictionary.